# CKR_KEY_TYPE_INCONSISTENT: when deriving signing key in FIPS mode using SunPKCS11 with NSS

Tags: java, aws-sdk, jce, fips, nss

Environment details:
Java: openjdk-1.8.0.312
OS: RHEL8

Following are the security providers configured.
SunPKCS11-NSS-FIPS,
SUN 1.8,
SunEC 1.8,
SunJSSE 1.8

Note:

- The issue disappears when added a new JCE. Worked when added SunJCE or BouncyCastleFipsProvider security provider.
- Have confirmed unlimited strength crypto availabel (via Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") =~ large number)

```html
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: init() failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Mac.engineInit(P11Mac.java:208)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.chooseProvider(Mac.java:350)
    at javax.crypto.Mac.init(Mac.java:415)
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AbstractAWSSigner.sign(AbstractAWSSigner.java:127)
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_KEY_TYPE_INCONSISTENT
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_SignInit(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Mac.initialize(P11Mac.java:177)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Mac.engineInit(P11Mac.java:206)
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Any pointers please?

Comment: Appears to be the same problem as https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8278640 but in a non-TLS context. The first comment there claims you can fix it with a config setting. Since the problem is in the PKCS11 provider using NSS, as you already said using a different provider will also work.

Comment: Right, this seems to be a known issue and fixed in RHEL with OpenJDK17 - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6778751

Comment: To me, this looks more like [RH2102431: SecretKey generate/import operations don't add the CKA_SIGN attribute in FIPS mode](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2102431), fixed in `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.332.b09-4.el8`.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with RHEL8 + OpenJDK1.8, resolutions/workarounds mentioned - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6778751